# draw iimages in web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this image](http://postimage.org/image/9jf45eqef/) and I want to display it in web page
with the regtangles as drop down menu

do you have any idea to  do this 
without putting images in background with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML `map` and `area` tags to declare preset areas on the image: http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/area.html

The drop downs could then be applied to the click event of the area.

```
<map>
    <area shape="rect" coords="0, 1, 2, 3" onclick="dropdownClickEvent">
</map>
```